# Oracle capture count of minus operation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables (TABLE_A & TABLE_B) where I'm using the MINUS command to see if there are differences in the tables.

In my example below you can see that TABLE_A has an additional row.

Is there a way to capture the numeric difference between the two tables, in this case 1 row.

If there is a difference >0 then display the value. Although my example is small it could contain many rows. Therefore I would only like to do the MINUS command once if possible. I'm also also amenable to alternative solutions and not tied to the MINUS command or if this can be done with SQL only that will work too.

Thanks in advance for your expertise and all who answer.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A(
 seq_num NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
nm VARCHAR(30)
);
/

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B(
seq_num NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
 nm VARCHAR(30)
);
/

BEGIN
 FOR I IN 1..4 LOOP
  INSERT INTO TABLE_A (nm) VALUES('Name '||I);
end loop;

FOR I IN 1..3 LOOP
  INSERT INTO TABLE_B (nm) VALUES('Name '||I);
end loop;

 END;
 
-- MINUS operation

SELECT nm FROM TABLE_A
MINUS
SELECT nm FROM  TABLE_B;

Output:
NM
Name 4

Pseudo code

Do minus command

If difference >0 then display rows
```

Comment: what is "numeric difference"? Number of rows returned by minus?

Comment: select count(*) to get the #rows.

Comment: Sayan Malakshinov the difference is number rows returned by MINUS. If greater than 0 I want to display the missing rows

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for this, you can try 1 as below -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT nm FROM TABLE_A
         MINUS
        SELECT nm FROM TABLE_B);
```

Another method maybe -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE_A A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM TABLE_B B
                    WHERE A.nm = B.nm)
```

Comment: Ankit Bajpai thanks for responding. While the count part looks okay is there a way of saying count>0 then display the missing rows possibly without issuing the query again as per my psuedo code?

Comment: May you plz share how your end result should look alike.

Comment: Ankit Bajpai sorry for the delay. I need the count into a PLSQL anonymous block variable (cnt). If cnt>0 THEN putline('1 row missing from table_b') end if. That's all I need. As I'm breaking this into two pieces. The second piece is the SQL I provided in my example

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly you can do it using analytic `count`:

```sql
select *
from (
   select v.*,count(*)over() cnt
   from (
      SELECT nm FROM TABLE_A
      MINUS
      SELECT nm FROM  TABLE_B
   ) v
)
where cnt>=4;
```

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0ac62f3d1ea835f60427a1da8efb965e

Comment: Sayan Malakshinov thanks for responding. The issue here is the hardcoded 4. I have to deploy this in over 50 environments so I need a more generic solution as per my psuedo code

Comment: @Beefstu I haven't understood what exactly do you need instead of 4... You can store this value in a special table or where you want and use it in the query, for example `where cnt>=(select value from my_params where key='numrows')`

Comment: I need this part in SQL

Where cnt<0 then
SELECT nm FROM TABLE_A
      MINUS
      SELECT nm FROM  TABLE_B